# Track number of clicks on shared content by a particular facebook user

Tags: share, facebook-apps

Is it possible to track number of clicks on shared content by a particular facebook user?

E.g.

Person A shared an article from external website onto his facebook timeline. Person B and Person C click on the link. It is consider 2 clicks even they click multiple times.

To fulfill this, what are the possibilities? Develop a facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking whether a dynamic link can created for the share button, then by using $facebook->getUser(); to get the userid, I could add a tail to the dynamic url something like &ref=userid.